Are Stampedes Dangerous to Participants?
Let's say a herd of wild bison are grazing when lightning strikes in the distance. The thunder scares enough of the bison to cause a stampede. What happens now?
My Hypothesis: Once a few of the scared bison start moving, a few other follow, and then more follow those ones, until the entire herd is running. The herd runs in a more or less straight line, maybe diverting around objects or turning due to hills. After a while some individuals start to slow down, causing other individuals to slow down, until the entire herd comes to a stop.
That series of behavior could be very easily simulated with a Boids algorithm. One interesting aspect of the Boids algorithm is that individuals rarely intersect. If real stampedes behave like a boids algorithm, then we would therefor expect individuals to not hit each other, leading to very few casualties among the herd.
I wanted to know if this prediction was true, so I tried doing research on it. Unfortunately, my research came up very dry. I found plenty of article on crowd-crunch (a.k.a. human stampedes), but I feel like that is a very different phenomena than a cattle stampede. Searches on Google Scholar turned up papers about cancer and crowd-crunch. Does anyone have information on this topic, or better search terms I could use for researching?

Interesting, maybe look at swarm intelligence,
Swarm Intelligence: A Review of Algorithms 2017 by Amrita Chakraborty & Arpan Kumar Kar (Springer)
